# SOQL for GroupId for a Portal Account

Tags: soql

I want to get respective GroupIds for List of Portal Accounts ()

Right Now I am doing it this way:

```
SELECT Id,RelatedId FROM Group WHERE RelatedId IN (SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE PortalAccountId IN : accountIds)
```

Is there a way, where I can do it in Single query something like below(Related Id stores UserRoleId):

```
SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Related.PortalAccountId IN : accountIds
```

By the way following is Working:

```
SELECT Id,RelatedId, Related.Name FROM Group
```

Comment: Your first example _is_ a single query. Why are you looking to change its structure?

Comment: I am working in code optimization piece, and trying to save CPU time wherever possible

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is no, you have already hit upon the best possible query for your scenario.

Comment: note that [SOQL time is not counted as part of CPU time](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339361&type=1&mode=1) and `Group.RelatedId` is [polymorphic](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys)